# Применить анимацию ко всем ссылкам, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Как мне сделать так, чтобы не писать для каждой ссылки отдельную функцию, а сделать универсальную, ссылок порядка 20. Вот так у меня выглядит сейчас:

```js
$("a[href^='#ranking']").on('click', function() {
    var target = $('#ranking');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});

$("a[href^='#pull']").on('click', function() {
    var target = $('#pull');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А нет возможности добавить один общий класс всем элементам? Чтобы сразу их выделить классом вместо `a[href^='#pull']`

Comment: можно использовать `$("a[href^='#']")` для всех якорей

Comment: Или, записывать их в удобном виде - - https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/p92wgd60/

Comment: Ну, когда у тебя несколько тысяч якорей на сайте это не особо удобно делать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, вот так вот. С общим классом для всех якорей.

```js
$("a.yak").on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#pull' class='yak'>yak</a>
<a href='#pull2' class='yak'>yak2</a>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="pull">
toyak
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="pull2">
toyak2
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```